# TYPO3 - One page website

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Is there some best approach to create one page website in TYPO3 ?
My idea is to create navigation in TypoScript and FCEs for every segments so I can link it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a one page template as an extension for TYPO3, this can be downloaded from GitHub.

http://github.com/maximilian-mayer/t3onepage

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's a nice approach. 
You can too use javascript to generate the menu based on the number of FCE you find in the content.

The two approach are nice.
I had to mind on this problem for my work.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage all contents by their content id. First add one header and then add one FCE for that header part. Header becomes your menu. Note that you use separate grid for all section(one header and one FCE).

[Create a subpart menu for a one page template in typo3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722773/create-a-subpart-menu-for-a-one-page-template-in-typo3)
check this link for menu in one page site.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it either in pure TS or in fluid.

1. TS-solution:
   for navigation use a HMENU as usual, but modify the links to be anchor-links
   for the content use another HMENU but instead of the links generate the whole content from that page, for example with a CONTENT object (using the uid from the current (menu)-page as pid for selection). dont forget to insert the anchor.
2. fluid-solution:
   do the same, but instead of TS use the according VHs from ext:vhs: `v:page.menu`, `v:render.record`